# How do I use it only in the frontend theme?

Tags: javascript

Using the jQuery Update module, I set version 1.8. This version "broke" the views UI in the Admin theme; it seems that the AJAX calls in the Views UI work only with jquery 1.5.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery Update 7.x-3.0-alpha2 and later, there is a setting that allows to change the jQuery used for a specific theme; you can select:

- The site default version (set with the jQuery Update module)
- The version that comes with Drupal
- Any version supported by the jQuery Update module

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'library_alter') {
    if(isset($implementations['jquery_update'])) { 
      // Move jquery update to the end. This will make sure our hook_library_alter
      // is always called before the jquery_update.
      $jquery_update = $implementations['jquery_update'];
      unset($implementations['jquery_update']);
      $implementations['jquery_update'] = $jquery_update;
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_library_alter().
 */
function mymodule_library_alter(&$libraries, $module) {
  // If it is the admin theme all we want to do is change the global $conf
  // variable so when jquery_update runs right after us it will use 1.5.
  // We are not using path_is_admin(current_path()) because some admin path can use
  // the frontend theme like node edit page
  global $theme_key;
  if (variable_get('admin_theme') == $theme_key) {
    // Modifying global $conf variable, can be dangerous. Be carefull.
    global $conf;
    $conf['jquery_update_jquery_version'] = '1.5';
  }
}
```

from http://antistatique.net/blog/2013/01/04/drupal-use-a-different-jquerys-version-for-the-frontend-and-backend/

Answer (score 0):

You can use my patch from [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/888334). It will add per path settings, like on the following mockup:

[image: mockup]

Patch code [here](https://drupal.org/files/jquery_exclude_0.patch), and also below:

```
*** jquery_update.module    Fri Sep 28 01:53:48 2012
--- jquery_update.module    Tue Oct 08 11:12:58 2013
***************
*** 68,77 ****
--- 68,83 ----
    // We are updating just the system module. For all other cases we return.
    if ($module != 'system') {
      return;
    }

+   // We don't want to alter if we are on one of the excluded paths
+   if(drupal_match_path(current_path(), variable_get('jquery_update_exclude_paths', ''))) {
+     return;
+   }
+       
+       
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'jquery_update');

    // Make sure we inject either the minified or uncompressed version as desired.
    $min = variable_get('jquery_update_compression_type', 'min') == 'none' ? '' : '.min';
    $cdn = variable_get('jquery_update_jquery_cdn', 'none');
***************
*** 146,155 ****
--- 152,167 ----
        'microsoft' => t('Microsoft'),
        'jquery' => t('jQuery'),
      ),
      '#default_value' => variable_get('jquery_update_jquery_cdn', 'none'),
      '#description' => t('Use jQuery and jQuery UI from a CDN. If the CDN is not available the local version of jQuery and jQuery UI will be used.'),
+   );
+   $form['jquery_update_exclude_paths'] = array(
+     '#type' => 'textarea',
+     '#title' => t('Disable jQuery update on the following paths'),
+     '#description' => t('You are allowed to use wildcards, for example admin/*'),
+     '#default_value' => variable_get('jquery_update_exclude_paths', ''),
    );

    return system_settings_form($form);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use dev version, that has already commited patch allowing to set different version for administrative pages: https://drupal.org/node/1524944

Comment: Sadly, it still does not allow to use original jQuery version to be selected. This issue is still open.